# Store variables within a class from a query

Tags: php, class

I have an images class in which I want to run a query once the class is initiated (on login), and then `store` the variables such as `profile_picture_thumb` .etc in the class, or atleast access them in other functions via `this`. The following is not working, and returns the `this` fields as blank.

```
class Images
{
    var $main_prepend = 'm_';
    var $thumb_prepend = 't_';
    var $default_ext = 'jpg';
    var $cropfactor;
    private $prepLocation = '';
    private $profile_picture_thumb = '';
    private $profile_picture_large = '';
    private $facebook_id = '';
    public function __construct()
    {
        $sql = Nemesis::select("profile_picture_thumb, profile_picture_large, facebook_id", "users", "id = '{$_SESSION[user_id]}'");
        list($profile_picture_thumb, $profile_picture_large, $facebook_id) = $sql->fetch_row();
        $this->profile_picture_thumb = $profile_picture_thumb;
        $this->profile_picture_large = $profile_picture_large;
        $this->facebook_id = $facebook_id;
        if (local()) {
            $prepLocation = XAMPP;
        } else {
            $prepLocation = '';
        }
    }
    public function profilePic($show = true, $delete = false)
    {
        if ($show) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(function() { $("#profile-picture").tipsy({fade: true}); });</script>';
            if (is_file(ROOT . $this->profile_picture_thumb)) {
                echo '<img src="' . reduce_double_slashes('../' . $this->profile_picture_thumb) . '" id="profile-picture" class="profile-picture" title="Your Profile Picture">';
            } elseif (!empty($this->facebook_id)) {
                // if there is no profile picture set, and user has listed fb profile picture, get profile picture
                $fb_p_thumb = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$facebook_id}/picture";
                $fb_p_large = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$facebook_id}/picture?type=large";
                echo '<img src="' . $fb_p_thumb . '" id="profile-picture" class="profile-picture" title="Facebook Profile Picture">';
            } else {
                echo '<img src="images/50x50_placeholder.gif" id="profile-picture" class="profile-picture" title="Click to add profile picture">';
            }
        }
        if ($delete) {
            if (is_file(ROOT . $this->profile_picture_thumb) || is_file(ROOT . $this->profile_picture_large)) {
                if (!unlink(ROOT . $this->profile_picture_thumb) && !unlink(ROOT . $this->profile_picture_large)) {
                    $msg->add('e', "Could not delete user profile picture!");
                }
            } else {
                $msg->add('e', "Files not found in directory.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
public function __construct()
{
    static $prepLocation = '';
    static $profile_picture_thumb = '';
    static $profile_picture_large = '';
    static $facebook_id = '';

    $sql = Nemesis::select("profile_picture_thumb, profile_picture_large, facebook_id", "users", "id = '{$_SESSION[user_id]}'");
    list($profile_picture_thumb, $profile_picture_large, $facebook_id) = $sql->fetch_row();
    $this->profile_picture_thumb = $profile_picture_thumb;
    $this->profile_picture_large = $profile_picture_large;
    $this->facebook_id = $facebook_id;
    if (local()) {
        $prepLocation = XAMPP;
    } else {
        $prepLocation = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the query is successfully executed with result returned ?

Comment: So what specifically is the problem you are having? Is it a problem setting the class properties or reading the class properties? What efforts have you made to narrow down the problem via debugging?

Comment: Ok so the main issue was I was missing `$this` with the facebook id and thats what I was viewing. Dumb me. Aside from that when I try and call the Images class in my config file as $images_core = new Images. Then I call somwhere else $images_core->profilePic(); the query fails as with a `Fatal error: Call to a member function profilePic() on a non-object`

Comment: This is not an issue however, if I do not call the new class in the config. and call it in the page.

Comment: nevermind. it was because I was calling it inside an old template that was based on procedural code

Comment: **You should never do any computation in contructors!!!** You should only assign parameters there.

Comment: it makes sense to me. since __constructor gets initiated in the config file once, and these variables that do not change get `stored`